# How to get the number of processes waiting for CPU on Linux?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

If CPU is running 100% usage, other processes should be put inside a run queue. Which command can I use to get the size of the run-queue? `vmstat` seems to return a related value of the CPU like below:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 875128 576328 2147136    0    0     1     4    3   11  0  0 99  0  0
```

According to the manual, "`r`: The number of runnable processes (running or waiting for run time).", the column `r` indicates the number of processes including both running and wait processes. How can I just get the number the waiting processes?

Comment: Related info about definition of "runnable process": http://www.linfo.org/runnable_process.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of *runnable* processes is given by `procs_running` in `/proc/stat`:

```
awk '/procs_running/ { print $2 }' /proc/stat
```

Subtract the number of CPU threads available, stopping at 0, and you’ll get the number of scheduling units (processes or threads) waiting to be scheduled. You can determine the number of CPU threads available from `/proc/stat` too, using the `cpu?` lines. Overall:

```
awk '/cpu[^ ]/ { nb = substr($1, 4); if (nb > nbcpus) nbcpus = nb };
/procs_running/ { runqueue = $2 - nbcpus; if (runqueue < 0) runqueue = 0; print runqueue }' /proc/stat
```

Comment: Is `lscpu` command used to get the number of available CPU threads? The calculation would be `Thread(s) per core` * `Core(s) per socket` * `Socket(s)`?

Comment: You can look at the `CPU(s)` line from `lscpu`, or calculate the value from `/proc/stat`; see my update.

Comment: According to this article: https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/processstates_20120831.pdf  the definition of runnable is `When a process is in a Runnable state, it means it has all the resources it needs to run, except that the CPU
is not available.` So in this case, I don't need to substract the number of CPU available threads, right?

Comment: No, runnable in `/proc/stat` doesn’t distinguish between running and runnable, it looks at the task state; note that in the article you link to, both states are the same.